# Error when login Bluemix container command line

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud

After I successfully login using "cf login", when I try to run the command: "cf ic login" (or "cf ic init"), I get the message: 
"Deleting the old configuration file...
Retrieving client certificates for IBM Containers...
FAILED

Error getting response, check your network connection"

But my network connection works fine, and other cf commands work fine too.

Do you know what is causing the issue and how I can solve this?

Comment: Can you try using the new bx CLI (http://clis.ng.bluemix.net/ui/home.html) and let us know if the issue persists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it a consistent issue? If so, you may firstly need to check your container resource on your Org/Space. It can be checked on your Bluemix Profile 'Manage Organization' and you can see your container quota on the space you tried to login.

Comment: Thanks for the response, indeed it turned out to be linked to the Bluemix account that I was using.